# Suppress the wildcard function in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is there any way to suppress the wildcard function in DOS? I'm trying to rename a file i.e.

`c:\Temp\Acer_CardMS_ForConversion_01_20150623.txt ACERMS*CARDMSACER01.txt`

and the result I'm getting is `ACERMSardMS_ForCARDMSACER01.txt`

I actually want the `*` in the name so need to suppress the function it serves.

Comment: Try to rename it with the explorer, it will not work

Answer (score 6):

Operating system doesn't support wilcard (*) character in filenames or folders, like next :

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

These characters are operating system reserved and cannot be used in filesystem operations.

Comment: Related MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Alternatively you can try to use ∗ (U+2217 ASTERISK OPERATOR)

Comment: @Benoit Or better not, as it would create problems sooner or later. Although NTFS swallows it happily, it will create problems with: FAT, ascii-based FTP, webpages, sharing file with *nix based systems, fonts. (eg, ∗ looks like triangle on my desktop)